# Problems with indenting tags that follow headers

Tags: html, css

I am dealing with web pages that I cannot edit. I am trying to indent all tags under nested headers to a level of indent equal to the header. H1 = indent 0px, H2 indent = 20px, H3 indent = 30px, etc. Tags under each header can include img, table, div, p, etc. Each H1 may have one or more H2, each h2 may have one or h3, etc. Also note that Headers will never skip when nested, H2 will always follow H1, h3 will always follow H2, etc.

I have had partial success.

Using the following css:

```css
h1,h1~p,h1~table,h1~div {
  margin-left: 0px!important;
}
h2,h2~p,h2~table,h2~div {
  margin-left: 20px!important;
}
h3,h3~p,h3~table,h3~div {
  margin-left: 40px!important;
}
h4,h4~p,h4~table,h4~div {
  margin-left: 60px!important;
}
h5,h5~p,h5~table,h5~div {
  margin-left: 80px!important;
}
h6,h6~p,h6~table,h5~div {
  margin-left: 120px!important;
}
```

```html
<h1>header 1</h1>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div txt</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p >p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<p>div text</p>
<h4>header 4</h4>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h5>header 5</h5>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h6>header 6</h6>
<p>p text</p>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div txt</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<p>div text</p>
<h4>header 4</h4>
<p>p text></p>
<div>div text</div>
<h5>header 5</h5>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h6>header 6</h6>
<p>p text</p>
```

The result is as follows. Notice how once Header 1 repeats, the indent of the tags that follow each header do not reset to a zero indent as with the first iteration of H1 and the nested headers and tags under the first Header 1.

The goal is to have each iteration of H1 start over with an indent of zero.

[image]

Comment: I have found that the problem appears to be with the presence of headers tags If I don't use Header tags in test HTML, the indents work as expected. Adding the header tags causes the indents to fail as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

`h2, h2 ~ p, h2 ~ table` has been overriding `h1, h1 ~ p, h1 ~ table`. Because `h2` and `h1` have the same level as `table` but `h2 ~ table` has come after `h1 ~ table`.

If you want to have `h1` style application. You should put `h1, h1 ~ p, h1 ~ table`, after `h2, h2 ~ p, h2 ~ table` like below

```css
h2, h2 ~ p, h2 ~ table {
  margin-left: 20px!important;
}
/*Moved `h1` to the 2nd place after `h2`*/
h1, h1 ~ p, h1 ~ table {
  margin-left: 0px!important;
}
h3, h3 ~ p, h3 ~ table {
  margin-left: 40px!important;
}
h4, h4 ~ p, h4 ~ table {
  margin-left: 60px!important;
}
h5, h5 ~ p, h5 ~ table {
  margin-left: 80px!important;
}
h6, h6 ~ p, h6 ~ table {
  margin-left: 120px!important;
}
```

```html
<h1>header</h1>
<p>text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>text</p>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you and I apologize. This solution does not work. I have edited the post to show a better example of the output that I am currently experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to insert a Javascript snippet into these web pages?

If yes, then insert this code. It will add classes to your HTML, then you will be able to use these classes to indent tags.

```js
function indentIt(tagName = 'h1', className = 'indent-h1', tags = 'DIV,P') {
    document.querySelectorAll(tagName).forEach((el) => {
    t = tags.split(',');
    let x = el.nextElementSibling;
    while (t.includes(x.tagName)) {
        x.className = x.className + ' ' + className;
      x = x.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
}

indentIt('h2', 'indent-h2');
indentIt('h3', 'indent-h3');
indentIt('h4', 'indent-h4');
indentIt('h5', 'indent-h5');
indentIt('h6', 'indent-h6');
```

```css
h1,
.indent-h1 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

h2,
.indent-h2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h3,
.indent-h3 {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

h4,
.indent-h4 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

h5,
.indent-h5 {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

h6,
.indent-h6 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>header 1</h1>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div txt</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p >p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<p>div text</p>
<h4>header 4</h4>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h5>header 5</h5>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h6>header 6</h6>
<p>p text</p>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div txt</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h3>header 3</h3>
<p>p text</p>
<p>div text</p>
<h4>header 4</h4>
<p>p text></p>
<div>div text</div>
<h5>header 5</h5>
<p>p text</p>
<div>div text</div>
<h6>header 6</h6>
<p>p text</p>
```

Comment: Thank you and I apologize. This solution does not work. I have edited the post to show a better example of the output that I am currently experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I cannot edit the html.